# scrapy scrape extra field in linked page

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some posts on the primary page where almost everything i need is there. But on the link(ed) page there is a date field I additionally need. I tried a callback with the following:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from macnn_com.items import MacnnComItem

from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class MacnnSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'macnn_com'
    allowed_domains = ['macnn.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.macnn.com']
    posts_list_xpath = '//div[@class="post"]'
    item_fields = { 'title': './/h1/a/text()',
                    'link': './/h1/a/@href',
                    'summary': './/p/text()',
                    'image': './/div[@class="post_img"]/div[@class="post_img_border"]/a/img/@original' }

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over posts
        for qxs in hxs.select(self.posts_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(MacnnComItem(), selector=qxs)

            # define processors
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # skip posts with empty titles
            if loader.get_xpath('.//h1/a/text()') == []:
                continue
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
                loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
            request = Request(loader.get_xpath('.//h1/a/@href')[0], callback=self.parse_link,meta={'loader':loader})
            yield request
            #loader.add_value('datums',request)
            yield loader.load_item()

    def parse_link(self, response):
        loader = response.meta["loader"]
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        hero = hxs.select("//div[@class='post_header']/h2/text()").extract()
        loader.add_value('datums',hero)
        return loader
```

But I get errors like

> ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'XPathItemLoader' in `<GET http://www.macnn.com/articles/13/06/14/sidebar.makes.it.easier.to.jump.between.columns/>`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_link` needs to return an item, not the loader.

```
def parse_link(self, response):
    loader = response.meta["loader"]
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    hero = hxs.select("//div[@class='post-header']/h2/text()").extract()
    loader.add_value('datums',hero)
    return loader.load_item()
```

Comment: I don't have the error anymore, but i don't get item 'datums' either :(

Comment: btw there was a type (post-header to post_header). Bu the loader.add_value('datums',hero) does not add something to items.

Comment: I saw that i did a "print hero" after the hero statement what destroyed my hero probably. Removed that and worked like a charm.

Comment: Also removed the " yield loader.load_item()" in the primary parse function, otherwise i get everything twice (with and without the datums field).